# inline / inplace editing for different form inputs in Ember

Tags: ember.js

Views in the app we're developing are already written in Handlebars / Emblem and data is already taken from models.

I'm trying to figure out what's the best approach for inline / inplace in Ember. Problem: when nothing is clicked, the data is just a text. When you click the text depending on its type (date, plain text, list of items) the corresponding input field (date field, text field or select) is replaced and you can edit it.

Have you had experience with this issue? If so, please share your thoughts!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one solution using an [Ember.Component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html):

```
App.InlineEditComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    toggleEditing: function() {
      this.toggleProperty('isEditing');
    } 
  }
});
```

With the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/inline-edit">
  {{#if isEditing}}
    <form {{action "toggleEditing" on="submit"}}>
      {{yield}}
    </form>
  {{else}}
    <span {{action "toggleEditing"}}>
      {{value}}
    </span>
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

#### Usage:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars"  data-template-name="index">
  {{#inline-edit value=someProperty}}
    {{input value=someProperty type="date"}}
  {{/inline-edit}}
</script>
```

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OGEnOdA/2/edit

You can add more features (for example, end editing on focus-out the form element, etc.) but I think you get the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you, Panagiotis. I think I tend to overuse Ember components (not view-components) and had a problem that I would add them in as many places as possible except simpler solutions. I tried out your solution and I'm sure that it has definitely pros over other solutions but I finally I chose https://github.com/mszoernyi/ember-inplace-edit with custom modifications. Anyway I think that answer deserves acceptance as it may be better than current one - I have some problems with communication with controller and customizing events. :)